# Implementing kind of a delegation pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have two classes, `A` and `B`. What I am trying to do is to pass data from `A` to `B` after receiving a message from sockets.

This is simplified look of how classes are defined:

class A:

```
export default class A {
  client;
  callbacks;
 
  constructor() {
    this.callbacks = {
      open: () => this.client.logger.debug('open'),
      close: () => this.client.logger.debug('closed'),
      message: (data) => {this.client.logger.log(data)}, //I want to pass this data object to class B
    };
    
    this.client = new Spot(constants.apiKey, constants.apiSecret, {
      baseURL: constants.baseURL,
      wsURL: constants.wsURL,
    });

    this.client.userData(listenKey, this.callbacks);

  }
}
```

I already have a property of A in class definition of B:

```
export default class B {
  account;

  constructor() {
    this.account = new A();

    
  }
}
```

What would be a correct/standard way to connect these two so I get a 'data' object from class A every time the socket message callback from class A is triggered?

I am a bit new with `JS`, but on `iOS` we would use a delegation pattern, with a protocol, that says:

1. class `A` will have a delegate property.
2. A delegate (class `B`) must implement a protocol (in this case it would be a requirement to implement method called `didReceiveMessage(data)`.
3. After that, when a message is received in class `A`, we would just do(in socket message callback shown above) something like this.delegate.didReceiveMessage(data).

Protocol usage here is not important generally, but it is a plus, cause from `A` class, we can only access `didReceiveData(data)` method trough a delegate property, and nothing else (other properties / methods of class B are not visible). At least that is how it works in `Swift/Obj-C`. I just mentioned it, cause I am curious is this how it is done in JS too.

I guess there is some similar mechanism in `Javascript`, or some more standard/better way to achieve this kind of data sending between objects?

Comment: Did you mean "data object from class B"?

Comment: @Barmar No, I mean data object, from message callback, from class A (to pass it to class B...

Comment: Do you mean the `data` parameter to the `message` function?

Comment: I mean, to pass data object from here `message: (data) => {this.client.logger.log(data)}` to a class B. Something like this `message: (data) => {this.delegate.didReceiveMessage(data)}` and somewhere in a B class, to have method that is automatically triggered everytime this callback(from class A) is triggered by a socket client.

Comment: JS has proxies, but I don't know much about them.

Comment: I just checked proxies. Seems it could be a good way to go. Have to give it a try.

Comment: @Barmar Absolutely no need for proxies here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on iOS we would use a delegation pattern, with a protocol

You can do it exactly as you described:

```
export default class A {
  client;
  delegate;
 
  constructor(delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    
    this.client = new Spot(constants.apiKey, constants.apiSecret, {
      baseURL: constants.baseURL,
      wsURL: constants.wsURL,
    });

    const callbacks = {
      open: () => this.client.logger.debug('open'),
      close: () => this.client.logger.debug('closed'),
      message: (data) => this.delegate.didReceiveMessage(data),
    };
    this.client.userData(listenKey, callbacks);
  }
}

export default class B {
  account;

  constructor() {
    this.account = new A(this);
  }
  
  didReceiveMessage(data) {
    console.log(data); // or whatever
  }
}
```

There is no interface (protocol) declaration that would tell `A` which properties and methods it may access on the passed `delegate`, but the contract exists of course. You should document it in prose. (Or use TypeScript).

Notice also how your class `A` interacts with the `Spot` client, it uses very much the same pattern of passing an object with event handler methods.

A simpler pattern in JavaScript, if you just need a single method in your protocol, is to pass a callable function only:

```
export default class A {
  client;
 
  constructor(onMessage) {
    this.client = new Spot(constants.apiKey, constants.apiSecret, {
      baseURL: constants.baseURL,
      wsURL: constants.wsURL,
    });
    this.client.userData(listenKey, {
      open: () => this.client.logger.debug('open'),
      close: () => this.client.logger.debug('closed'),
      message: onMessage,
    });
  }
}

export default class B {
  account;

  constructor() {
    this.account = new A(this.didReceiveMessage.bind(this));
    // or inline:
    this.account = new A(data => {
      console.log(data); // or whatever
    });
  }
  
  didReceiveMessage(data) {
    console.log(data); // or whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, TypeScript is probably what would be better for me, cause I am coming from a  type-safe language. I tried method with passing a  bound function through the A class constructor, and it works. Thanks a bunch for the example! :)

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert on NodeJs, but you can use something like an [emitter plugin](https://github.com/jeffrose/emitter).

In javascript, it would look like this:

```
function A() {
    Emitter(this);
    
    this.action = function() {
        console.log("something happened");
        
        this.emit("action", { prop: "value" });
    };
}

function B(a_instance) {
    // subscribe to "action" event
    a.on("action", function(data) {
        console.log(data.prop); // "value"
    });
};

var myA = new A();
var myB = new B(myA);

myA.action();
```

Comment: Ok, this looks good. I was more into some solution without additional plugins, but if nothing better comes out, I will try with this. I just thought there is some "built-in" mechanism / way... Will try this for sure though, thanks.

Comment: @Whirlwind i think nodejs has something built-in: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html